# i9505 Firmware upgrade question

Tags: system-info, baseband

just a quickie:
I just updated (i9505) from XXUEMKE to XXUHOH2
Location Germany - dbt running CM12.1
So far all ok - no problems.
My Question:
After Flash (BL + Modem + WLAN) it´ll still Show XXUEMMKE as Baseband. Using APP "Phone Info": It shows the same XXUEMKE as baseband except under latest Firmware installed  it Shows XXUHOH2 installed.

So, why does the new Firmware not Show under Information - Baseband? What am I missing? And even that Odin said all ok. Is it really installed and running? (maybe I forgot something?)

greetx 2 all you out there.....

Comment: If I remember correctly - you need to flash the modem a second time to actually change the values. No idea why but when I had a galaxy S4 it was a common question in lot's of forums.

Comment: yeah, forgot to mention - did that ... same result. so that is not it.